# Cygwin: unable to install paramiko from local directory

Tags: python, pip, cygwin, paramiko

I have Cygwin installed as a portable app on a remote desktop and I want to install paramiko 2.4.

**I tried using pip to install paramiko directly with no success**

```
G01203109@BDSPUKD00060150 /lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ pip install paramiko
Collecting paramiko
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 328, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

**I am not sure if this is a proxy issue due to network restrictions.
so I downloaded paramiko and put it in a directory, Then I tried installing  from local directory. No success**

```
G01203109@BDSPUKD00060150 /para
$ pip install -e /para paramiko-2.4.0.tar.gz
Processing ./paramiko-2.4.0.tar.gz
Obtaining file:///para
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko==2.4.0)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 328, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Due to network restriction Cygwin has to be portable so Cygwin is installed in a folder on my desktop.

Anyone has any clue what I can try next to install paramiko 2.4 on portable cygwin?

**Paramiko dependency Cryptography is already installed:**

```
G01203109@BDSPUKD00060150 /lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ pip install cryptography
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=11.3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=11.3->cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from packaging->cryptography)
```

Any clues on what I can try next?
Thanks,

Comment: current paramiko for cygwin has a large patch, so probably you need to patch the code. https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fpython-paramiko%2Fpython-paramiko-1.15.2%2B20150921%2Bgit7b33770-1-src&grep=paramiko

Comment: Can you install any other packages?  Is the problem somehow *just* with paramiko?  From the traceback I don't see any reason it should be.

Comment: Here I was able to install perl from local directory just fine. I can run cygwin setup and pick paramiko package, but doing it that way cygwin only installs paramiko 1.16 but I need more recent version of paramiko to leverage the new features like MAC and others. Any thoughts? or I am stuck with paramiko 1.16?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, I ended up installing paramiko 1.18 which has the features I needed. But it was a little painful process because I will try to install it from local directory..then paramiko install will fail because for whatever reason it was unable to install a dependency package..(again I am suspicious this is due to some proxy issue that is preventing paramiko from installing dependent packages) So I will manually install that package..And I will try install paramiko again.. I did this until all required dependencies were manually installed. Painful process.but hey..did the job